# JOptionPane in Java

Tags: java, joptionpane

Does anyone know why tab (\t) does not work with JOptionPane.showMessageDialog?

My code is as follows:

```
 String addText = "NAME\t\tADDRESS\t\tTEL.No\tEMAIL\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < addressBookSize; i++) {
           addText = addText+entry[i].viewAllInfo();
        }
        System.out.print(addText);
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, addText);
```

Are there other ways to align text in JOptionPane?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels How?

Comment: My answer was wrong; it is possible to use `\n` for a new line, as described in Sun's [How to Make Dialogs tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features): "You can split the message over several lines by putting newline (`\n`) characters inside the message string."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put your tabbed text into JTextArea

```
String addText = "NAME\t\tADDRESS\t\tTEL.No\tEMAIL\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < addressBookSize; i++) {
           addText = addText+entry[i].viewAllInfo();
        }
        System.out.print(addText);
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JTextArea(addText));
```

Comment: I would avoid using tabs for this as their spacing can be unreliable, especially if there is data that crosses more than one tab length. Better to use String.format(...).  Again, the Font would need to be Font.MONOSPACED

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your data again, I'd probably display it in a JTable, and then if desired, would display this in a JOptionPane or in a GUI.  If you need simpler, then display it in a JTextArea whose font has been set to monospaced, and use String.format(...) or something similar to allow your Strings to be displayed in a table.